# How to use .jar file in as3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

Do we use .jar file in our Flash AS3 project? I need to import .jar file in my project?

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if YOU use .jar files in your AS3 projects. But .jar is JAVA archive so, I think that you can't run Java compiled code from AS3 (or AS3 from JAVA)

Comment: @Adam Harte thanx and i know it's a valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAR files are typically compiled Java code, which can be opened by the Java Virtual Machine. Java is owned and updated by Sun Microsystems.

SWF files are compiled ActionScript code, which can by opened by the ActionScript Virtual Machine. ActionScript (used by Flash) is owned and updated by Adobe.

The two are similar, but created by different companies, and aren't really able to interact in any way.

Answer (score 5):

Simple question, simple answers:

1.

> Do we use .jar file in our Flash AS3 project?

Please ask your boss or your collegue whether you are using .jar files or not.

2.

> I need to import .jar file in my project?

If you are using jar files in your project, you probably will need to import them.

Comment: Thanks alot but this is not the answer of my question.

Comment: Then you need to make your question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Since Java's JAR files are stored as ZIP files, you can actually open them in AS3 (using any of the many AS3 ZIP libraries out there) and extract out each individual class file or asset.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to do? If so, I can go into detail on the steps involved.

Comment: JavaScript files? why are you talking about JavaScript?

Comment: @adam-harte Sorry, I have been working with JavaScript all day and made a typo. :P Thanks, typo fixed.